# Call constructor using an arguments object in javascript?

Tags: javascript

Is it possible to call the constructor using an arguments object?

```
var MyClass = function(a, b){
  this.a = a;
  this.b = b;
};
var myClassInstance = function(){
  //This line would not work, but is what I'm asking. Is there a way besides eval?
  return new MyClass.apply(?, arguments);
}('an A value', 'a B value');
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, you could do this:

```
var myClassInstance = function(){
  return MyClass.apply(Object.create(MyClass.prototype), arguments);
}('an A value', 'a B value');
```

Comment: This is not a very good answer in my opinion. Don't just post code, explain what it does, how it works, why you would do it, etc.

Comment: It's important to note that new returns the create object automatically if not returned from the constructor.  The following is more correct.  `function mynew(Klass, arguments){ var o = Object.create(Klass.prototype); return Klass.apply(o, arguments) || o }`

Answer (score 2):

Yes it is.

However, I had to rewrite your code a bit, as the method you're currently using appears to put the function calls into the global scope.

```
function MyClass(a, b){
    this.a = a;
    this.b = b;
};

function myClassInstance(){

    //The apply function will apply MyClass attributes to this object.
    //The apply function itself returns nothing.
    MyClass.apply(this, arguments);
    console.log(this); //Should show the a and b variables

    return this;
}

new myClassInstance('an A value', 'a B value');
```

Comment: Viable way to do it, however for taking up less lines of code I used Raynos' variation. Thank you :)

Comment: @Beanow Fair enough. Remember that the `apply` function doesn't return anything though.

Comment: True I used an extra statement to store the object so I can return it.